# Doctrine search by string is not working with one word only

Tags: symfony, doctrine

I use this function to get results by searching into comment field.

```
public static function findByString(QueryBuilder $qb, string $searchString): QueryBuilder {

    $orxExpression = $qb->expr()->orX();
    
    $orxExpression->add(
        $qb->expr()->orX(
            $qb->expr()->like("CONCAT(person.firstname, ' ', person.lastname)", ':searchString'),
            $qb->expr()->like('person.comment', ':searchString'),
        )
    );
    
    $qb->andWhere($orxExpression);
    $qb->setParameter(':searchString', '%' . $searchString . '%');
    
    return $qb;
}
```

Let's say i have this string in comment: "This text is very long".

When i search for word "very" i don't get any results, when i search for "is very" i get the person object as expected.

I really can't find where is the problem here.

I do expect when i search by only one word to get also a result that i want.

Comment: Can you provide the final output query and param values? You can get it from Symfony Profiler in the Doctrine tab.

Comment: You are passing an already defined `$qb`, if it already has a condition it could be as simple as that: with the new `andWhere` it provides no matches. Inspect the generated query as suggested above and go from there.